# Can Selenium wait for multiple elements staleness in parallel (Java)?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, wait

Except implementing myself multi threading, does Selenium has mechanism to wait for multiple elements in parallel to be stale?

I'm using this to wait for a single element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);  //3 = timeout
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
```

I have 30 elements that recreated simultaneously, I don't won't to block the code for 30*3 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to wait 30*3 secs. Each thread will start almost instantly right ? if so then your total wait will be ~3 secs only.

Comment: Yes, I asked how to do it if I won't implement multi threading myself.

Comment: You can add a third argument to the webdriverwait constructor which changes the default sleep time of 0.5 seconds between polling for the condition. Reduce it to something like 100 ms (constructor needs in milliseconds). Before coding up a concurrent solution measure out the time the single threading is taking. If you going for a concurrent approach I suggest you use the Future and Callable classes of the java.util.concurrent package. Easier to return values to the main program with this.

Answer (score 0):

**selenium does not do that.**

my advice: pick the element that takes the longest and wait for that one.

Comment: It all happen in parallel, and all elements takes the same time to wait for, that's the issue

Comment: @user3364652 If it all happens in parallel, why not waiting for **one** element, and then just verifying that all other elements are also stale??

Answer (score 0):

`wait.until` blocks the code only until the condition is met. The timeout is the maximum amount of time.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
```

In your code if `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf` is true after 1 second `wait.until` will block for 1 second. If `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf` already true in the first check the code will continue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use NgWebDriver : https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver.

You can wait until all page elements are ready, must use library for Angular websites